# How can I tell if my YouTube message was received by the right person?

Tags: youtube

I sent someone a private message over YouTube, and then checked my Sent messages box to see if it went through.

[image]

As you can see, the only username on the page is mine. I cannot double check who the message was sent to.

How can I tell if my message was received by the right person?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Community > Messages > Sent page there isn't an indication of to whom was sent a private message and there aren't read receipts for Youtube private messages either so you should wait to get an answer from the recipients to get confirmation that they received each private message and confirm to whom the private messages was sent.

**References**

[Send and receive private messages - Youtube Help](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/57955?hl=en)

Comment: So I won't know who I sent it to until s/he replies? Also, do you get a bell notification of receiving a private message on Youtube?

Comment: AFAIK, yes and yes.